# Parallelizing a while loop with arrays read from a file in bash

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I have a while loop in Bash handled like this:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r -a line;
do
    myprogram ${line[0]} ${line[1]} ${line[0]}_vs_${line[1]}.result;
done < fileinput
```

It reads from a file with this structure, for reference:

```
foo   bar
baz   foobar
```

and so on (tab-delimited).

I would like to parallelize this loop (since the entries are a lot and processing can be slow) using GNU parallel, however the examples are not clear on how I would assign each line to the array, like I do here.

What would be a possible solution (alternatives to GNU parallel work as well)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Use-a-table-as-input:

"""
Content of table_file.tsv:

```
foo<TAB>bar
baz <TAB> quux
```

To run:

```
cmd -o bar -i foo
cmd -o quux -i baz
```

you can run:

```
parallel -a table_file.tsv --colsep '\t' cmd -o {2} -i {1}
```

"""

So in your case it will be:

```
cat fileinput | parallel --colsep '\t' myprogram {1} {2} {1}_vs_{2}.result
```

Answer (score 11):

I'd like @chepner hack.
And it seems not so tricky accomplish similar behaviour with limiting number of parallel executions:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r f1 f2;
do
    myprogram "$f1" "$f2" "${f1}_vs_${f2}.result" &

    # At most as number of CPU cores
    [ $( jobs | wc -l ) -ge $( nproc ) ] && wait
done < fileinput

wait
```

It limit execution at max of number of CPU cores present on system. You may easily vary that by replace `$( nproc )` by desired amount.

Meantime you should understand what it is not honest distribution. So, it not start new thread just after one finished. Instead it just wait finishing all, after start max amount. So summary throughput may be slightly less than with parallel. Especially if run time of your program may vary in big range. If time spent on each invocation is almost same then summary time also should be roughly equivalent.

Comment: I like this solution, but instead of `wait` I used `while [ $( jobs | wc -l ) -ge $( nproc ) ]; do sleep 3; done` ?

Comment: Are you speaking about the first `wait`? Yes, this may have the sence

Answer (score 10):

`parallel` isn't strictly necessary here; just start all the processes in the background, then wait for them to complete. The array is also unnecessary, as you can give `read` more than one variable to populate:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r f1 f2;
do
    myprogram "$f1" "$f2" "${f1}_vs_${f2}.result" &
done < fileinput
wait
```

This does start a single job for *every* item in your list, whereas `parallel` can limit the number of jobs running at once. You can accomplish the same in `bash`, but it's tricky.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with a max process cap? Otherwise running it on large input blows up -- edit, nevermind see Hubbitus's answer

Comment: Is it possible to have several commands together? Like, where would I put "&" in the following to get a process for each line in my file?

```
while read l; do
    myprogram $l
    if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then X="Succes"; else X="failure"; fi
    result="${result}\n${l}: ${X}"
done < file.txt
wait
echo result
```
https://pastebin.com/snBQKmhH