# Using parallel in bash script in order to processing grouped input files

Tags: linux, bash, parallel-processing, gnu

I have a bash script which processing each file in some directory:

```
for (( index=0; index<$COUNT; index++ ))
do
    srcFile=${INCOMING_FILES[$index]}
    ${SCRIPT_PATH}/control.pl ${srcFile} >> ${SCRIPT_PATH}/${LOG_FILE} &
    wait ${!}
    removeIncomingFile ${srcFile}
done
```

and for few files it works fine but when the number of files is quite large is too slow. I want to use this script parallel to processing grouped files.

Example files:

server_1_1    |    server_2_1    |    server_3_1
server_1_2    |    server_2_2    |    server_3_2
server_1_3    |    server_2_3    |    server_3_3

script should processing files related to each server parallel.
First instance  - server_1*
Second instance - server_2*
Third instance  - server_3*

Is it possible using GNU Parallel and how it can be reached?
Many thanks for each solution!

Comment: Why run just one command in background and then wait? Makes more sense if doing several at once...

Comment: [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52971764/for-loop-bash-scripts-parallel/52972662#52972662) might help you. It is logic to spawn commands in background and wait for them. There's even a POC version of a spooling script. That page also has lots of useful info about `parallel`.

Comment: Nothing in your code relates to the server numbers you mention! What are the pipe symbols (`|`) trying to tell me?

Answer (score 1):

I can't make head nor tail of what your question is trying to say, but I suspect the following will make a reasonable starting point. You put your actual code inside the `'...'` instead of the dummy actions I have used:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Do stuff for server 1
parallel -k 'echo server_1_{} ; date >> log_1_{}' ::: {1..3}

# Do stuff for server 2
parallel -k 'echo server_2_{} ; date >> log_2_{}' ::: {1..3}

# Do stuff for server 3
parallel -k 'echo server_3_{} ; date >> log_3_{}' ::: {1..3}
```

**Sample Output**

```
server_1_1
server_1_2
server_1_3
server_2_1
server_2_2
server_2_3
server_3_1
server_3_2
server_3_3
```

**Log files created**

```
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff     29 30 Oct 21:04 log_1_1
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff     29 30 Oct 21:04 log_1_2
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff     29 30 Oct 21:04 log_1_3
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff     29 30 Oct 21:04 log_2_1
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff     29 30 Oct 21:04 log_2_2
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff     29 30 Oct 21:04 log_2_3
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff     29 30 Oct 21:04 log_3_1
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff     29 30 Oct 21:04 log_3_2
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff     29 30 Oct 21:04 log_3_3
```

Answer (score 1):

The grouping part confuses me.

I have the feeling you want them grouped because you do not want to overload the server.

Normally you would simply do:

```
parallel "control.pl {}; removeIncomingFile {}" ::: incoming/files* > my.log
```

This will run one job per CPU thread.

Consider spending 20 minutes on reading chapter 1+2 of "GNU Parallel 2018" ([printed](http://www.lulu.com/shop/ole-tange/gnu-parallel-2018/paperback/product-23558902.html), [online](https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1146014)). I think it will help you understand the basic uses of GNU Parallel.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a lot of servers which should be monitored. Prepared files from each server are provided to one machine where script processing them in date order. This date is a part of file name fe. TYPE1_server01_20181030_194002.out. After file processing the data are inserting into database. Based on this I can prepare availibility report etc. I want to processing those files parallel, for each server in date order.